# Why have I been stopped from asking questions?

Tags: discussion

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this questions of those who are controlling the site.

I have asked 2 questions recently, before that not for a few months.  1 question closed due to opinion - fair enough & another that had some positive response.  So not sure, would like an explanation.

likely, because some don't like my views or points (is that a good enough reason?), albeit everything is quoted from the bible.

Look forward to an explanation, should be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Please read: [**What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/256282)

There have been several types of problems with some of your past questions:

- Not a question at all

  - https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/44580/2757
- Questions asking for theological synthesis (ie, systematic theology) instead of the analysis of individual texts

  - [Why is Jesus the favoured son of God over all others?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/44598/2757)
  - https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/49883/2757
- Theological questions that do not refer to any texts or are requests for verses

  - https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/47375/2757
- Unclear questions with several comments explaining why they're unclear which you never responded to

  - [Did Jesus die on the Cross & was he a spirit or not?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/49833/2757)
  - [Matthew 12:31-32 is the Holy spirit higher than God / son of God?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/49839/2757)
- Questions asking for opinions

  - [On the basis Paul was not one of the 12 Apostles should we follow him when he asks us to imitate him such as 1 Corinthians 4:15-16?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/52775/2757)

All of these have been rightly closed - they are not what this site is about.

If you are now getting the automatic question ban, there is nothing that we mods can do. We didn't apply this ban to you, and we do not have the ability to lift it.

There are two things you can do:

1. Fix your existing closed questions. The best candidates for being reopened are the ones that were closed for being unclear. Maybe some of the others can be edited to be on-topic too.
2. Wait six months for the system to let you post another question.

Comment: not sure I would agree with a number of points, received good replies / answers regardless, if people agreed or not.  We will just pointlessly go around in a circle. comments noted.

Comment: If you think any of these questions were wrongly closed, feel free to start a new Meta question to put forward your case that it should be reopened. (If you do so, please make a new Meta question for each one.)

Comment: @anothertheory - It's alright, understanding the exact 'scope' of BHSE can take a bit of time, and it's not unusual for newer users to need a few attempts to develop their questions to focus on original texts and intentions rather than theological angles. I remember needing a few attempts on many of my early questions, which can be a frustrating experience. You're right that you shouldn't feel targeted based on your views or opinions - as Dannii has said, feel free to use Meta questions to highlight any specific concerns, knowing that we all try to follow the same clear rules and guidelines.

Comment: @SteveTaylor & curiousdannii - thank you for your reply, I thought alot are quite old questions, did not think that they would still be relevant now as a criticism, but no problem.  many thanks